Cant see report after changing query?
I have been trying to use dates in my report. Initially I had default date parameters set to start and end
=DateAdd("d", -(DatePart(DateInterval.Weekday, Today()) + 7), Today()) =DateAdd("d", -(DatePart("w", Today(), FirstDayOfWeek.Sunday) -1), Today())
respectively.
I ended having to change that because the online reporting service worked fine except it didnt allow for subscriptions to be set to an expression instead of a datetime value.
The workaround was changing the default date to 01/01/1800 and 01/02/1800
(dates i know dont have data)
and changing the query so instead of having a filter over top now including the parameters in the query and checking if the default is 1800 dates.
however now i get multiple errors such as

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

or

There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/PreviewProcessingServce33344/ReportProcessing that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more deatils.

or
server did not provide a meaningful reply might be caused by contract mismatch or premature shutdown or internal server error.
I am running this version of Oracle for the DB: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
This is the query I am currently using:
WHERE Highlights.FSR_ID = Contacts.mmm_EMPLOYEE_ID
       AND Highlights.AC_ID = AC.ID
       AND AC.MODEL_ID = Model.ID
       AND AppLookup.ID = Highlights.NOTIFICATION_LEVEL_ID
       AND (
              Highlights.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN CASE
                     WHEN :startDate = '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM' THEN (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14)
                     ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
              END
              AND CASE
                     WHEN :endDate = '1/2/1800 12:00:00 AM' THEN (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 1)
                     ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:endDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
              END
       )
       AND Contacts.ID = :FSR_ID


Are you binding the variables as timestamps, or as strings? If they are timestamps (as they probably should be) then you shouldn't be comparing them with strings or calling to_timestamp() for them. If they are strings then check the actual format and values sent. (You seem confused about the format; in one place it has the time, in another it doesn't?)

@AlexPoole the actual entries are timestamps, the parameter in visual studio is set to "Date/time", so im not sure if thats the same as timestamp. what do you suggest? use timestamp for all or???

If they are timestamps and being passed as such then your SQL code is relying on implicit conversion to strings, which is never a good idea. Just treat the bind variables as timestamps. You said you changed the code but you already had defaults, so how were you passing and using those in your SQL? You should also look at the server logs to try to find the actual error being thrown.

Your current code will only work for the boundary case you've mentioned, eg
SQL> variable startDate varchar2(30)
SQL> exec :startDate := '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select
  2    CASE
  3       WHEN :startDate = '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM' THEN (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14)
  4       ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  5   END
  6  from dual;

CASEWHEN:STARTDATE='1/1/180012:00:00AM'THEN(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'IW')-14)ELS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
27-MAY-24 12.00.00.000000000 AM

SQL>
SQL> exec :startDate := '10/10/2024 12:00:00 AM'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select
  2    CASE
  3       WHEN :startDate = '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM' THEN (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14)
  4       ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
  5   END
  6  from dual;
     ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')
                        *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

If the dates are truly coming in as the format as per your fixed string, then the format mask needs to reflect that, eg
SQL> variable startDate varchar2(30)
SQL> exec :startDate := '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select
  2    CASE
  3       WHEN :startDate = '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM' THEN (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14)
  4       ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  5   END
  6  from dual;

CASEWHEN:STARTDATE='1/1/180012:00:00AM'THEN(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'IW')-14)ELS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
27-MAY-24 12.00.00.000000000 AM

SQL>
SQL> exec :startDate := '10/10/2024 12:00:00 AM'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select
  2    CASE
  3       WHEN :startDate = '1/1/1800 12:00:00 AM' THEN (TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14)
  4       ELSE TO_TIMESTAMP(:startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')
  5   END
  6  from dual;

CASEWHEN:STARTDATE='1/1/180012:00:00AM'THEN(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'IW')-14)ELS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
10-OCT-24 12.00.00.000000000 AM


I get the same error when I try to preview my report in VS Studio, that being There was no endpoint listening at net pipe:/localhost/PreviewProcessing Service22676/ReportProcessing that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See Inner Exception, if present, for more details. The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/PreviewProcessingService22676/ReportProcessing' could not be found on your local machine. not sure what the issue is other than i am doing something in an unsupported way
the code works in dev but im having the same issue in VS

If your values are being passed as dates or timestamps, not as strings, then you are relying on implicit conversion, and also assuming incorrect formats for what the implicit conversion would produce.
You said 'the parameter in visual studio is set to "Date/time"' but it's unclear (to me anyway) which Oracle data type that corresponds to.
If they are dates then treat them as dates:
Highlights.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN CASE
    WHEN :startDate = date '1800-01-01'
    THEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14
    ELSE :startDate
    END
AND CASE
    WHEN :endDate = date '1800-01-02'
    THEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 1
    ELSE :endDate
    END

If they are timestamps then treat them as timestamps; as your WHEN clause currently generates a date the real timestamp would also need to be cast to that data type, assuming created_date is also a date:
Highlights.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN CASE
    WHEN :startDate = timestamp '1800-01-01 00:00:00'
    THEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14
    ELSE CAST(:startDate AS DATE)
    END
AND CASE
    WHEN :endDate = timestamp '1800-01-02 00:00:00'
    THEN TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 1
    ELSE CAST(:endDate AS DATE)
    END

Alternatively, particularly if created_date is a timestamp, make them both evaluate to timestamps:
Highlights.DATE_CREATED BETWEEN CASE
    WHEN :startDate = timestamp '1800-01-01 00:00:00'
    THEN CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 14 AS TIMESTAMP)
    ELSE :startDate
    END
AND CASE
    WHEN :endDate = timestamp '1800-01-02 00:00:00'
    THEN CAST(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'IW') - 1 AS TIMESTAMP)
    ELSE :endDate
    END


You're using current_date which is based on your session locale, which might be fine, but be aware it might give different results for users in different time zones. And between is inclusive, but if all of your values are at midnight then it might not be doing quote what you expect - it would only match values at exactly midnight on end_date (or current_date  - 1), not anything later that day. If that isn't what you intended then you can use a range.

this is very helpful, while all of these work I get the same error when I try to preview my report in VS Studio, that being
There was no endpoint listening at net pipe:/localhost/PreviewProcessing Service22676/ReportProcessing that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See Inner Exception, if present, for more details. The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/PreviewProcessingService22676/ReportProcessing' could not be found on your local machine.
not sure what the issue is other than i am doing something in an unsupported way

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

OK, but those errors don't tell us anything about what is going wrong. You have ot get the actual errors from the logs on the server. If it isn't your service you'll have to ask for them.

i see, i dont currently have access to the server logs, tho I did not run into issues when trying out an older much simplier query where I just put a filter on top of the query in VS Studio.
My only guess here is they all have CASE as a commonality as a keyword that i never used before. so im wondering if maybe I could switch this to Use if statements instead

You can't use if in plain SQL, only PL/SQL. If you can't see the actual error you're a bit stuck. You might be able to see the actual bind value and data type being sent I suppose, from your end.

I guess my other thought is weather it has something to do with trunc/date function keywords, its all more confusing, given that works fine in dbeaver testing but not VS
